# Regex Split - Works Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have the following Jquery and Regex:

```
 $("[class^=ipsum-img],[class^=ipsum-img-]").each(function(){
                          var x = $(this).attr("class");
                          console.log(x.length);
                          if (x.length>8) {
                                   var m = x.split(/(\d+)[^-]*$/g);
                          console.log(m);                   
                          }
                          else{
                                     console.log("short");       
                          }

              });
```

I am looking for all instances of the class ".ipsum-img" and ".ipsum-img-xxxxxx" .

For every occurrence, I get the length of the class.

If the length is > 8 , I can make the assumption the is the class ".ipsum-img-xxxxxx"

In the case that it is "ipsum-img-xxxxxx", I need to use regex, and parse out the "xxxxxx" from the class name.

I am using the following regex:

```
   var m = x.split(/(\d+)[^-]*$/g);
   console.log(m);
```

In my console, I see the following:

**Array [ "ipsum-img-", "000000", "" ]**

**Array [ "ipsum-img-ffffff" ]**

**Array [ "ipsum-img-efefef" ]**

It appears that the regex is only creating the split for the first instance. I checked my page source, and verified that those are the only three classes on the page.

Why is the only working once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression looks for a string of one or more digits followed by any number of characters that aren't `-` up to the end of the string. Neither `"ipsum-img-ffffff"` nor `"ipsum-img-efefef"` match that.

Personally I wouldn't do it with `.split()` anyway:

```
var matched = /ipsum-img-(\d+)$/.exec(this.className);
var number = matched && matched[1] || null;
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern matches decimal digits, but you have hexadecimal digits in the strings. Make a set with decimal digits and a to f:

```
var m = x.split(/([\da-f]+)[^-]*$/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, the pattern I needed was:

```
var matched = /ipsum-img-([\a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.exec(this.className);
 var number = matched && matched[1] || null;
```

Comment: So _Pointy_'s answer apparently gave you the idea to fix it, just replaced `(\d+)` with `([\a-zA-Z0-9]+)`. You should accept _Pointy_'s answer to close the question.

Comment: Had to wait until I was able too.